# Magento Admin - Please Select Products to Add

Tags: php, magento

When creating an order within the admin section, you get the 'Please Select Products to Add' how can I change the code to only show Configurable products within the grid instead of all the products?

Answer (score 2):

To limit the admin order creation process to configurables only, you need to add a product type filter to the collection which the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid class is using.

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('type_id','configurable');
```

This can be accomplished in different ways, whether via a block rewrite using Magento's nifty configuration-based classname rewriting or by using an observer (the latter being the preferred way).

Post a comment if you need help with the observer or rewrite config.